# What is the $ sign for when mapping a network drive

Tags: windows-7, networking

So silly question when you map a network drive in windows 7 what is the dollar sign for at the end e.g. \Computername\drivename$ ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The `$` designates an [administrative share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share).

Administrative shares are intended to allow system administrators to access whole volumes on a remote computer. For example, `C$` represents the `C:` volume on the remote computer. Administrative shares also allow access to other resources, such as printers connected to the remote machine (`print$`). They are hidden by default in Windows Explorer, cannot be accessed by limited users, and cannot be permanently deleted (only hidden).

Answer (score 0):

A $ means that the share is hidden.  Windows will not show hidden shares while browsing, the user has not know they exist.

Comment: Correction: Windows Explorer will not. There are explorer replacements or alternates that do show the hidden shares. The correct term would therefor be that a $ share is an administrative share.